# wxnotebook dynamic image display

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to display images that I get from a folder in a Wxnotebook. The problem that I don't know how many images is in that folder ( I only have images full path). How can I display images dynamically with wxnotebook?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problem did you have when you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I display images dynamically with wxnotebook?

Here are hint for your homework to be easy

1. Load Those List from That Directory - See wxDir
2. Create [wxImageList](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_image_list.html) from loaded image see the docs
3. [Assign  wxImageList](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_with_images.html#a8436e7fdc49a5a23fdca2effebd319ef) to wxNotebook
4. [Set Page](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_notebook.html) using specific index in image list above